# Why is doing a client query with Apollo causing a Network Error?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I am trying to run a query using graphql, but keep getting a Network error. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { ApolloProvider, gql } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

import { NETWORK_INTERFACE } from './src/utils/constants'
import { colors } from './src/utils/constants';
import Main from './src/Main';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: NETWORK_INTERFACE
    // http://localhost:3000/graphql
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

console.log('Tesset')
client.query({
  query: gql`
    query GetPosts {
      getPosts {
        text
        _id
        createdAt
      }
    }`
}).then(result => console.log(result));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={colors}>
          <Main />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

The client.query() causes  following error.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network error: Network request failed]
* http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144904:32 in ApolloError
```

I'm using graphql in the back-end with no issues. Able to do posts and and gets etc. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: inspect/compare raw network request/response

Comment: 127.0.0.1 or [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is an address that means "this computer" -- is the GraphQL server you're trying to access running on the mobile device or emulator that's running your application?

Comment: I've tried running it both on my phone as well as an emulator on my computer but get the same error.